# How to use Bazel with Node.js

Tags: node.js, build, multilingual, bazel, monorepo

My understanding is that Bazel expects projects to be under a monorepo with a WORKSPACE file at the top-level and BUILD files in every project:

```
Repo
├── ProjectA
│   └── BUILD
├── ProjectB
│   └── BUILD
└── WORKSPACE
```

However, going through the [Bazel NodeJS rules documentation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs), it seems to suggest that every project should have it's own `WORKSPACE` file where it defines its dependencies. i.e. ...

```
Repo
├── ProjectA
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── WORKSPACE
└── ProjectB
    ├── BUILD
    └── WORKSPACE
```

This looks similar to a multi-repo with every project referencing other projects as an [external dependency](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html), which seemed okay to me, until I realized that for external dependencies, [Bazel requires all transitive dependencies to be specified in the WORKSPACE file for every package](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html#transitive-dependencies), which is definitely not ideal.

What's the easiest way to use Bazel with NodeJS projects, with some projects possibly written in other languages? Also, is there an example somewhere for Bazel being used in a multi-repo setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the 2 possible options are in fact

`Repo
├── MyProject
│   └── BUILD
├── third_party
│   └── ProjectB
│       └─ BUILD
└── WORKSPACE`

or

`Repo
├── MyProject
│   └── BUILD
└── WORKSPACE`

where in the second case WORKSPACE references ProjectB with `npm_install` rule as defined in https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs#using-bazel-managed-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to figure this out myself, but what I've gathered so far is that there is only one `WORKSPACE` file at the root of the repo. You need to have a `package.json` file (probably at the root) containing all the dependencies used in the whole repo then call `npm_install` or `yarn_install` in the `WORKSPACE` file to download them all.

Then your package `BUILD` file can reference a dependency with `@npm//some_package` as in:

```
filegroup(
  name = 'sources',
  srcs = ['index.js'],
)

npm_package(
  name = 'pkg',
  srcs = [ 'package.json'],
  deps = [
    ':sources'
    '@npm//lodash'
  ],
)
```

There are a few different dependency edge cases I haven't figured out yet so this may not be perfectly correct. Good luck.